# How to instruct Oracle 11g Standby database MRP to bring down as soon as applying the given archive log file?

Tags: oracle, rman, dataguard

**Scenario:**
Let us consider the following:
Oracle 3 node RAC.
RMAN Managed Recovery and Dataguard are configured between production and standby DBs.
The SCNs of 3 nodes are S1, S2, S3 at some point of time respectively. 
Smax=max(S1,S2,S3)
**Update1**(with reference to Balazs Papp Advice):
log_1_x.arc, log_2_y.arc, log_3_z.arc where log file sequence number x<y<z and they contain the sequence number Smax

Please advise on bringing down Orace 11g Standby database MRP as soon as applying the given archive log file with name, log_3_z.arc!

Comment: why do you want to do this? You already got an answer, but it seems that it does not satisfy you. So please describe what is the reason for this question.

Comment: MRP is brought down for some time to take its backup at that state and then it will be restarted to apply further logs!

Comment: and why do you stop the the MRP during the backup and do not make an online backup?

Comment: Why do you want stop the MRP to perform a backup? As long as you keep all your archivelog backups, you can perform a point-in-time restore to any scn.

Comment: If you actually want to stop managed recovery before a given SCN is applied then Balasz did already post how to do this.

Comment: It may not be the best practice! But, Lot of inserts/updates happen on the database objects after that state. It is time bound! If any of the job goes wrong, roll back/flashback to the state would take some time! So, CA Copy of that state is taken to start afresh as soon correcting the jobs! Please advise on bringing down the standby MRP as soon as the given log is applied!

Answer (score 1):

> archive_xyz.log contains the sequence number Smax

This is where you are wrong. You have 3 instances, you have 3 redo threads, so you have 3 archivelogs containing the change at `Smax`.

Because of this, you need to recover the database until SCN/change, not `"archive_xyz.log"`.

[image]

```
alter database recover managed standby database until change Smax;
```

Note that, this does not apply the change at `Smax`.

[managed_standby_recovery::=](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_1004.htm#i2079973)

> **UNTIL CHANGE Clause**
>
> Use this clause to instruct Redo Apply to recover redo data up to, but
>   not including, the specified system change number.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me! Please may I request your guidance in bringing down MRP only (not recovering) for some time for backup and then it will be restarted!

Comment: > "for some time for backup"

What do you want to do? This seems nonsense